# Using rankfiles with OpenMPI

Tags: mpi, distributed-computing, openmpi

I am trying to use MPI in a cluster and would like to be able to control which ranks get scheduled in which nodes.

**Note: I am using OpenMPI 2.1.0.**

For that I am using a rankfile. If I use the following rankfile:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-8-16:~/dist_log_reg$ cat rankfile 
rank 0=localhost slots=1
rank 1=54.153.103.12 slots=1
```

I get:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-8-16:~/dist_log_reg$ mpirun -v -np 1 -rankfile rankfile hostname
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
The rankfile that was used claimed that a host was either not
allocated or oversubscribed its slots.  Please review your rank-slot
assignments and your host allocation to ensure a proper match.  Also,
some systems may require using full hostnames, such as
"host1.example.com" (instead of just plain "host1").

  Host: ip-172-31-8-16
```

If I use only one entry in the rankfile:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-8-16:~/dist_log_reg$ cat rankfile 
rank 0=localhost slots=1
```

I get:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-8-16:~/dist_log_reg$ mpirun -v -np 1 -rankfile rankfile hostname
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
All nodes which are allocated for this job are already filled.
```

I have tried everything I can think of (e.g., installing other distributions of MPI and trying different options in the rankfile) but haven't been able to make this work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to create your error with passing `localhost` as `hostname`. But When I use the actual system-name I managed to run it.

```
rank X=myPC slot=Y
```

I believe that Open MPI probes the hostnames and performs a [gethostname](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/gethostname.2.html.) call.

Comment: I believe recent versions of MPI support both 'slot' and 'slots'. Both give the errors above.

Comment: hmm, Then I guess [this](https://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=tuning#using-paffinity-v1.3) FAQ is outdated. how about a rankfile like: `rank 0=ip-172-31-8-16 slot=1` Can you give this a try?

Comment: Yep, that works. Thanks! If you include this in your answer I will accept it.